# escape single quote or aphosthrope in filter datastage

Tags: filter, escaping, datastage, single-quotes

How to escape single qupte or apostrophe in filter stage-DataStage?
I've tried escape the symbol with backslash in any order of the regex below but it returns same result

```
nama_lgkp_ibu  like '^((?=.*[-!$@#^&*()_+|~=`{}\[\]\%\':";<>?,\\.\/])).{1,}$'
```

return:

```
Filter_83: Parse error: Expected 'is' statement ('is true', 'is false') or boolean operator (and, or) got: ":".
```

Is there any way to escape the single qupte character in datastage-filter?

Comment: The filter stage is not able to filter rows with a regular expression in a like - check out https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSZJPZ_11.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.ds.parjob.dev.doc/topics/t_deeref_Specifying_the_Filter.html

Comment: then how to filter certain column using regex in external filter?

Comment: Why do you think the filter stage is able to do regex? Have you seen it working (with simple examples)? As far as I know regex are available in th rules stage but this is limited to installations where Analyzer is licensed

Comment: pardon me, but it looks like in my office because I can run some simple filter-regex and I don't know if the analyzer is licensed but as far as I know the IIS Datastage server is licensed

Comment: any example for such simple ones? Do not mix it with regular SQL "like" filtering i.e. like 'A%' would be SQL and no regex.